How do I use page.evaluateOnNewDocument() in Puppeteer?
I have the following NodeJS code calling evaluateOnNewDocument():
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())

const fs = require('fs')

const preldpath = process.argv[2];
const url = process.argv[3];
const pdfpath = process.argv[4];

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: 'new'});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const preloadFile = fs.readFileSync(preldpath, 'utf8');
    await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(preloadFile);
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.pdf({path: pdfpath});
    await browser.close();
})();

The content of preloadFile looks like the following:
Object.defineProperty(navigator, "languages", {
  get: function() {
    return ["fr-ca", "fr"];
  };
});

I use the NodeJS script with the preload JavaScript file to open the following HTML file, but the languages still remain the default and have not been changed to "fr-ca fr". How to preload a JavaScript file to make navigator.languages different from the default?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Navigator Languages</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Your Preferred Languages:</h1>
    <p id="language-output"></p>

    <script>
        const languageOutput = document.getElementById('language-output');
        languageOutput.textContent = navigator.languages.join(', ');
    </script>
</body>
</html>


Does this answer your question? How to specify browser language in Puppeteer

No. language was just an example. I am trying to figure out how to make preload js file works.

Hmm. evaluateOnNewDocument works fine for me, maybe not this particular navigator override (it could be an inaccurate, or no-longer-working solution), but if that's not what you're trying to do, then don't use it as an example. What are you actually trying to do? Make your preloadpath file content foo = 42 and run console.log(await page.evaluate("foo")) after goto and you'll see 42 printed as expected.

You can use whatever proper example. I just want to a minimal example to demonstrate how to use evaluateOnNewDocument().

I just gave you one. Did you try it?

Error [ReferenceError]: foo is not defined. Please show me the whole program that works on your machine so that I can know what is wrong.

So it seems the error is that page.evaluateOnNewDocument(preloadFile) shall be page.evaluateOnNewDocument(preloadFile.toString()). I thought the input shall be a file buffer. But it actually should be a string?

Did you see my answer? preloadFile is already a string because you provided 'utf8' as the second arg, so .toString() isn't necessary. The problem is the content of the preload file, not the Node code that reads it. Use foo = 42 in the preload file, something simple that you can easily verify, rather than a complicated language hack that doesn't seem to work.

Based on the comments, it sounds like you just want to get evaluateOnNewDocument working and don't care about overriding navigator languages per se. The "preload" code example you've picked appears not to work on current browsers regardless of Puppeteer, much less evaluateOnNewDocument, so it's a non-starter.
Here's a less complicated minimal example to show the usage of the function:
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^22.7.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  const url = "https://www.example.com";
  browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await page.evaluateOnNewDocument("foo = 42");
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
  console.log(await page.evaluate("foo")); // => 42
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());

Whether you load the expression string from a file or not is irrelevant to the behavior of evaluateOnNewDocument, so I'd start by getting it working as a string, then move it out to a file once you've established that it works directly. Add lays of complexity gradually, only after verifying simpler versions work.
Here's the file version, although it's the same as any other file read in Node (use async fs operations since you're in an async func):
const fs = require("node:fs/promises");

// ...

const code = await fs.readFile("preload.js", "utf8");
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(code);

...where preload.js contains exactly foo = 42 and nothing more or less.
If you're unable to bridge the gap between this working example and your actual use case, please provide more details about what your actual goal is and exactly where you're stuck getting there.

BTW, I am not familiar with .finally(() => browser?.close());. Many puppeteer example does not use it. But it seems to be a preferred way. I want to know the best coding style in puppeteer. Do you have a good reference on it?

In your code, if an error is thrown during execution, then browser.close() will never be called and the process will hang until you kill it manually. finally ensures the browser is closed no matter what so the process can exit cleanly. The ?. is necessary because if the browser fails to launch, browser will still be undefined, and undefined.close() will throw. So this boilerplate handles all possible cases elegantly. Most Puppeteer code out in the wild isn't particularly exemplary and doesn't handle errors well.

If I use puppeteer.connect() instead of launch(), shall finally also include page.close() besides browser.disconnect()? Then finally() should be  .finally(() => { page?.close(); browser?.disconnect());?

Go ahead if you want, but probably. If you opened a page and the browser persists, you probably want to close it, unless you expect some other process will want the page. It's up to you based on your application-specific needs. The rule is generally: clean up what you allocate, and exit everything cleanly. Don't leak memory or leave zombie processes or unused memory lying around.

Does this answer resolve your question? If so, consider accepting it. I notice you don't accept many answers, and leave a lot of answers and comment threads hanging. It's good to know whether there are any lingering issues here or not. Follow-up is good courtesy, given that people are volunteering their time to help you (and future visitors, of course).
